# How to compile ffmpeg.c into shared library?

Tags: c, api, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

Is it possible to compile `ffmpeg.c` into the shared library? I need it in shared library form to link with my C program and call main function in `ffmpeg.c`.

Comment: Rename the `main()` in it and do as for any other shared lib to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. To do so you'd need to:

- Find out how you gonna pass the arguments (if via argc/argv no changes would be needed)
- Rebuild the object files linked into `ffmpeg` shared library with `-fpic`
- Pass the `-shared` option to the linker